# Column not available when all the values are null

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I have been using the `udf` function to make one extra column on certain logic and if there is anything wrong, I have used `try/catch` and return `None`.
So while processing multiple files few files the entire records have `None` as value. For example -

```
def func(response):
    try:
        a = json.loads(response)
        b = a['body']['xyz']
        return b
    except:
        return None

_func = udf(func)
df = df.withColumn('new_col', _func(df.response))
```

let's say this is my transformation stage and when in the next stage . I load this data create table out of 10 files ,few files fail when running -
`SELECT new_col from table_created_from_this_df`
because it only contains null values but is it the case?

`Error: alysisException: u"cannot resolve 'new_col' given input columns`

Comment: Following the description of your pb, I can't reproduce your error, can you please create a minimum verifiable and complete example ?

Comment: ok sure I will do